# Is the Scene It? Big Button Pad compatible with You Don't Know Jack?

Tags: xbox-360, you-dont-know-jack

Does anyone know if *You Don't Know Jack* for Xbox 360 will work with the Big Button Pad controllers used with the *Scene It?* games?

Comment: I doubt it, You Don't Know Jack has answers organized in a 'cross' pattern, which likely uses the coloured buttons on an xbox-360 controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes, it does work with those controllers, or so [multiple](http://xbox360.ign.com/articles/114/1148565p1.html) [reviews](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/608654-you-dont-know-jack/reviews/review-146074) claim. That leads me to believe that Scene It? games simply map the D-pad and buttons onto their special controllers, and thus YDKJ works with them too. (I suppose another way to test it would be to play Jack with a Rock Band guitar ...)